# Why does my merge sort put a random 4 in the end?

Tags: c++

My merge sort doesn't work correctly, it can sort the first values, but the last value "7" gets replaces with a "4".

I can't seem to figure out why.

I have already tried to adjust the n,q,p values to a 0-index array, but that doesn't help.

I have also tried to adjust the n1 and n2 values, but again with no luck

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;


// p = start of array
// q = center of array
// r = end of array

int A[8] = {2,4,5,7,1,2,3,6};

int p = 1; //Start value of the array
int q = 4; //Middle value of the array
int r = 8; //End value of the array

int L[4]; //Making a new array with 4 slots
int R[4]; //Making a new array with 4 slots



int n1 = q-p+1; //Range of the left array
int n2 = r-q; //Range of the right array

int main(){
for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++){ //Putting the first 4 values in the 
"left" array
    L[i] = A[p+i-1];
}
for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++){ //Putting the last 4 values in the 
"right" array
    R[j] = A[q+j];
}
int m = 0;
int n = 0;
for (int z = 0; z < 8; z++){ //The sorting algorithm
    if (L[m] <= R[n]){
        A[z] = L[m];
        m = m+1;
    }
    else{
        A[z] = R[n];
        n = n+1;
    }
}
cout << "Left array: ["; //Printing out the arrays
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
    cout << L[k] << " ";
}
cout << "]"<< "\n";
cout << "Right array: [";
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
    cout << R[k] << " ";
}
cout << "]"<< "\n";
cout << "Sorted A: [";
for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++){
    //cout << L[k] << '\n';
    //cout << R[k] << '\n';
    cout << A[k] << " ";
}
cout << "]"<< "\n";
return 0;
}
```

Gives the output:

```
Left array: [2 4 5 7 ]
Right array: [1 2 3 6 ]
Sorted A: [1 2 2 3 4 5 6 4 ]
```

Comment: This seems like a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: ask yourself after you take the last element out of L or R what does `L[m] <= R[n]` compare in the following loop iteration?

Comment: Maybe rerun your sorting algorithm with [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] and see what else could be wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't limit the index of L and R, In the last comparison, the R array overflows. `n = 4` , `R[4]` is unexpected.